# SSL error in Asp.Net MVC Smtp Attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, ssl

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5.1 web application hosted on WIN 2008 R2 64-bit.

I have a wildcard godaddy SSL installed for my web application: `*.mysite.com`.

I attempt to send out emails from the website using this tag in my web.config:

```
<smtp from="myemail">
    <network host="mail.server.com"
             enableSsl="true
             port="25"
             defaultCredentials="false"
             userName="myuser" password="mypass" />
</smtp>
```

I get the following error:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote    certificate is invalid according to validation procedure at System.Net.Security.SSLState.StarteSendAuthResetSignal

If I change the property value of `enableSsl = false` , I am able to send emails but when is set to true it gives me error above.

Note: My SSL on the webserver is `*.mysite.com`.  I am using the mail server: mail.server.com SSL connection... maybe I need to install the SSL from the mailserver to this webserver?

Comment: Certificates are bound to the domain name. Is that your mail server? Did you install a valid certificate for that server?

Comment: I did install a valid ssl wildcard certificate from Godaddy.  I did bind the ssl entry in IIS to *.mysite.com.  The website is on a web server separate from the mail server.

Comment: But the mail server's domain name is "server.com" the certificate you are citing is for "mysite.com".

Comment: The SSL certificate I am using on my web site is for mysite.com and the mail server is mail.server.com.  The mail.server.com server itself has its own SSL for *.server.com

Comment: I think you need to look at the mail server and see if it has a _valid_ certificate. Was it self-signed?

Comment: The mail server had a wildcard certificate installed but it was not configured correctly.  So I think one issue got resolved.  Since I am using EnableSSl I had to change port number to 465 but I get a timeout error, so this is the only issue I am in the processing of troubleshooting now.

Comment: Maybe firewall issue? Anyway, you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

First issue was that my SSL certificate was not properly installed on the mailserver.

The second issue was not a firewall issue. Its a Microsoft .Net issue. The .Net uses System.Net.Mail to send out mail and it only supports Explicit SSL which means that by default the connection starts as unencrypted on port 25. At the moment it does not support port 465, I will either have to keep using port 25 or use a third party control to allow port 465 to work with my web application. –